# Add a custom link to each image in WordPress gallery

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development

I need to add some partner logo images inside my custom theme. I'm using the WordPress gallery and the `get_post_gallery()` function to obtain the images URL that I will use to display the single logo images. I'm facing a problem now because I need to add an unique link for each image and these links will be different. I can't use plugins, someone has suggested that I install [custom images gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-custom-links/) plugin, but I'm unable to find a filter I can use or a good tutorial on how to add this possibility to WordPress gallery.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try doing it [like this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_gallery/#comment-642) - you can then do something like `<a href="https://example.com"><img ...></a>`

Comment: This will output the images src, I need to associate also an unique link for each image!I know how to output a link tag, the problem is how to set the href of the tag in wordpress!